# Git not creating merge commit when merging signed/annotated tag

Tags: git, merge

I'm expecting Git to create a merge commit when I merge a signed or annotated tag but instead it fast-forwards the branch pointer. I'm using Git version 2.17.0 on openSUSE Tumbleweed that comes with it.

According to the manpage of `git-merge(1)` it should create a merge commit in case of merging a signed/annotated tag:

> **--no-ff** Create a merge commit even when the merge resolves as a fast-forward. This is the default behaviour when merging an annotated (and possibly signed) tag that is not stored in its natural place in refs/tags/ hierarchy.

The sequence of commands which I issued looks like this:

```
git init foobar
cd foobar
git commit --allow-empty -m 'Empty root commit'
git checkout -b feature
git commit --allow-empty -m 'Feature one commit ahead of master'
git tag -a -m 'Feature ready for non fast-forward merge' ready-to-merge-feature
git checkout master
git merge ready-to-merge-feature
```

Unfortunately and unexpectedly the merge of the annotated tag `ready-to-merge-feature` does result in a fast-forward merge instead of creating a merge commit. The same unexpected behavior I observe with a signed instead of an annotated tag.

Are my assumptions wrong? Am I doing something wrong? What would be a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note the part of the manpage that you'd quoted that I've bolded below:

> This is the default behaviour when merging an annotated (and possibly
>   signed) tag **that is not stored in its natural place in refs/tags/
>   hierarchy**.

With the command sequence that you gave, the tag *would* be in its natural place, so the conditions for that default wouldn't apply.

This default was put in place to aid fetching a tag from a contributors repository as `FETCH_HEAD` in the maintainer's repository. Such tags are likely to be ephemeral, so if they have content (an annotation and/or signature) it's usually good to preserve that information in a merge commit. But, tags that are already under `refs/tags/` are likely to be part of the permanent state of the project, and thus the content should remain available without needing to be transferred to a commit.

The simplest solution would probably be to explicitly use the `--no-ff` option.

Comment: I noticed the text in bold too but cannot make any sense out of it. Shouldn't tags stored under the location `refs/tags` be the standard and thus the `--no-ff` behavior apply?

Comment: @TimFriske Yes tags under `refs/tags` are the standard, which is why they aren't considered for this. This is designed to preserve the content of ephemeral tags that are used by a contributor requesting the project maintainer to pull code in a given state. Tags that are already accessible under the `refs/tags` are likely to be part of the permanent state of the project, and thus not in danger of being lost.

Comment: Where would Git then expect ephemeral tags – that are used by a contributor requesting the project maintainer to pull code in a given state – in order to trigger a non-fast-forward merge by default embedding the signature of the possibly signed tag into the resulting merge commit, i.e. without explicitly passing to Git or configuring `no-ff` behavior for it?

Comment: @TimFriske that type of ephemeral tag would usually be stored temporarily as `FETCH_HEAD`. But typically that would be internal to running `git pull <remote> <tag-name>`.